# Select column when union two tables with one overlapping column name in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Here is the code (simulating full outer join for sqlite3):

```
SELECT EMP_ID, ID, NAME, DEPT FROM COMPANY LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENT ON COMPANY.ID = DEPARTMENT.EMP_ID 
union
SELECT EMP_ID, ID, NAME, DEPT FROM department LEFT OUTER JOIN company ON COMPANY.ID = DEPARTMENT.EMP_ID
```

The company table has the columns: id, name, age, address, salary.
The department table has the columns: id, dept, emp_id.

The problem is that both tables have the id column, but I only want to select the id column from company. How can I do this?

Comment: replace `id` with `null` in the department select?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using an alias:

```
SELECT EMP_ID, c.id, NAME, DEPT FROM COMPANY as c LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENT as d ON c.ID = d.EMP_ID 
union
SELECT EMP_ID, c.id, NAME, DEPT FROM department as d LEFT OUTER JOIN company as c ON c.ID = d.EMP_ID;
```

This nicely illustrate the result of a full outer join:

```
    3   Teddy   
    4   Mark    
    5   David   
    6   Kim 
    7   James   
    8   Kitos   
    9   Paul    
    10  James   
    11  James   
    12  James   
    13  James   
    14  James   
    15  James   
    16  James   
    17  James   
1   1   Paul    IT Billing
2   2   Allen   Engineering
77              Finance
```

Blank cells are null.